# Plot using scipy.signal.sosfreqz

Tags: python, filter, scipy

In the below script, I'm expecting the plot to show the frequency response of a digital bandpass filter with a passband from 300Hz to 3000Hz.

```py
import scipy.signal as spy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fs = 48e3  # sample rate
nyq = fs / 2
WnL = 300 / nyq   # cutoff relative to nypuist
WnH = 3000 / nyq
sos = spy.cheby1(N=3, rp=0.5, Wn=[WnL, WnH], btype='bandpass', 
        analog=False, output='sos', fs=fs)

w, h = spy.sosfreqz(sos=sos, fs=fs)
plt.plot(w, abs(h))
```

The plotted output is more like a very narrow bandwidth filter very close to DC.  Are my cutoffs defined correctly? Can anyone see my error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the argument `fs` in the call to `cheby1`, you must specify the cutoff frequencies in `Wn` in the same units as those of the given `fs`.  So you should be able to fix your issue by changing the `Wn` argument to use the frequencies expressed in Hz: `Wn=[300, 3000]`.

Here's the plot that I get when I make that change to your script:

[image]